# Implementing Concurrent Multi threading in XV6 OS

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, operating-system, xv6

In xv6 I want to add thread support (i.e **threads of same process exectue on multiple cores**). As a **step 1** of this I want to make threads part of process array so that even threads are assumed as processes and computation takesplace. I know that we should make changes in proc struct to make threads a part of process array, how exactly(which code to modify/add) I should achieve this?

there is a ptable in proc.c with a max of 64 elements.